# jQuery Hide TDs without specified content

Tags: jquery, html

Looking for a way to hide the `td`s in a `table` which don't contain the inline CSS attribute `width:12%;`

code example below.

```
<td class="" id="">
<td class="" id="">
<td class="" id="">
<td width="12%" class="" id=""><!-- don't hide me! --></td>
```

So, the first 3 `td`s should get hidden only...

Comment: $('table tr td[width!="12%"]').hide();       ))))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easier with CSS, but since you asked for a jQuery solution, something like this should work..

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $.each($('td'),function(){
      if ($(this).attr('width') !== "12%") {
          $(this).hide();
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First your html markup is invalid.

Then, use CSS instead.

```css
td:not([width])  { /* or if you want to just display 12% - td:not([width="12%"]) */
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="" id="">hide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="" id="">hide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="" id="">hide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="12%" class="" id="">block
      <!-- don't hide me! -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: td[width] display value should be "table-cell" instead of "block". Or just change the whole thing to td:not([width]) { display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure CSS, which will be more performant than jQuery (and will apply before the content has rendered on the page):

```css
td:not([width]) {
  display: none;
}
```

Or, more specifically:

```css
td:not([width="12%"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

This will apply a `display` of `none` to any `td` element which does not have a `width` attribute.

If you're not wanting a pure CSS solution, with jQuery you can use:

```
$('td').not('[width]').hide();
```

Or, again more specifically:

```
$('td').not('[width="12%"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tbl').find('td').each(function (index) {
            if (this.style.width == "12%") {
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: So many issues with your code.
- Why do you need to define that `index` in the anonymous function?
- Why are you using `this.style.width` if the rest is `jQuery` ? wouldnt `$(this).width` make more sense?
- Why are you using an empty `if` if you can avoid the `else` statement by simply using `this.style.width !== "12%"`?

Comment: thanks, I can see my mistakes. I will keep that in mind.